# Can I spoof my IP during an integration test? (Cypress/Codebuild)

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, continuous-integration, cypress, e2e-testing

My web app utilizes OneTrust cookie banners. Within the USA, certain states require unique cookie banners, such as California, compared to the other states. OneTrust supposedly utilizes its own geolocation tech, via a reverse IP lookup accurate to the city level. So I don't think the Cypress [set geolocation](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/16171) strategy (setting longitude and latitude) will help me. This strategy didn't make the desired cookie banner appear.

Locally, if I use a certain VPN to spoof California (I'm not located in California), I can get the desired custom cookie banner to appear since the VPN IP tricks OneTrust. Is there a way to accomplish IP spoofing via cypress? Looking at [an older GitHub issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/16171), it appears this was not possible via Cypress. However, it's been 2 years since that issue was closed and I'd like to check again.

If it's not possible, has anyone found a way to spoof IP address via AWS CodePipeline/Codebuild? I run my Cypress tests in the pipeline on a linux container there.

Comment: When using a VPN, your IP address is not "spoofed". Instead, the traffic actually _is_ coming from that IP. I'd refer to it as "redirection" rather than "spoofing".